# Pleasantly Dynamic Property of Around

Tags: implementation-details, properties, around

It's a rare occurrence when an improper lexicon is mete with forgiveness when coding. However, I was pleasantly surprised to stumble across the fact that

```
Around[3,5]["Error"]
```

Works just as well as

```
Around[3,5]["Uncertainty"]
```

which is astounding.

What's my question? Well, it's twofold:

1. Why does this work? `"Error"` doesn't show up in `Around`'s `"Properties"`. Is `"Error"` dynamically interpreted as `"Uncertainty"` or are their hidden properties like `"Properties"` itself? How would I discover those properties? These questions seem to require very low-level knowledge of MM so I have no idea how to answer them myself.
2. What.. are these property things? The name collides with other 'Properties' in MM so I don't know how to specify these types of object-dependent properties from the `Properties[]` object, etc.

Comment: It is defined that way (`getAroundProperty[Around[mu_, sigma_, ___], "Uncertainty" | "Error"] := sigma;` ) in the source, just not documented as such.

Most of your questions are answered in the admittedly (and necessarily) voluminous documentation, some require poking around - search the site for example for "spelunking tools".